# Is it ideal to use "<=" or ">=" to compare floating point numbers?

Tags: php, floating-point, operators

I know that I should not use `==` or `!=` to compare floating point numbers,but should I use the other comparison operators like `<` or `<=` to compare them?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? Did you try?

Comment: I don't have any evidence to prove that they are not feasible, but I have a doubt about "<=",is it equal to "<" + "==" or just "!>"? If it is the former case ，how can i use "<=" for compare floating point numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For floats, you can use PHP's [`bcmath`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension:

> For arbitrary precision mathematics PHP offers the Binary Calculator which supports numbers of any size and precision up to 2147483647 (or 0x7FFFFFFF) decimals, if there is sufficient memory, represented as strings.

In particular, [`bccomp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php) takes two arguments. It returns 0 if they're equal, 1 if the first argument is bigger, and -1 if the second argument is bigger. The third argument indicates how many decimal places of precision you're looking for.

```
bcmath('12.555437830', '12.555437829', 10);
// returns 1
```

Note one drawback of this function is that arguments are taken as strings, though PHP's loose typing *usually* makes this a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that comparing floating-point numbers for equality is often problematic is that floating-point arithmetic only approximates real arithmetic. Therefore, if we have two numbers `x` and `y` that were computed with floating-point arithmetic, evaluating `x == y` does not, in general, tell us whether the two numbers *x* and *y* computed with exact mathematics would be equal. In other words, asking if `x == y` does not give us, with certainty, the answer we want (unless we have carefully designed and analyzed the code for this purpose).

The same problem exists with relational operators such as `<`. If we have `x` and `y`, either or both of which differ from the ideally computed *x* or *y* by some small amount, then `x < y` may be true while *x* < *y* is false, or vice-versa.

There is no general solution to this problem. In some applications, the error may be tolerable. In some applications, it may be possible to derive a bound on the floating-point error *e* so that we can prove that, say, if `x < y-e` is true, then *x* < *y* is true. (But then, if `x < y-e` is false, we are not sure about *x* < *y*.) Thus, the appropriate solution depends on the specific application.